# Upsampling and interpolation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I am getting the same result after upsampling and interpolation. Do you have some suggestion what could be wrong?
Here is resample code where increase frequency from year to month:

```
upsampled = staff.resample('M').sum()
```

The result is:

```
upsampled
2016-01-31    17
2016-02-29     0
2016-03-31     0
2016-04-30     0
2016-05-31     0
2016-06-30     0
2016-07-31     0
2016-08-31     0
2016-09-30     0
2016-10-31    32
```

Then I do interpolation:

```
inter_poly = upsampled.astype(float).interpolate(method='spline',order=2)
```

And this is the result of interpolation:

```
2016-01-31    17.0
2016-02-29     0.0
2016-03-31     0.0
2016-04-30     0.0
2016-05-31     0.0
2016-06-30     0.0
2016-07-31     0.0
2016-08-31     0.0
2016-09-30     0.0
2016-10-31    32.0
```

I tried several options, but none of them works.

Thanks!

Comment: `interpolate()` only fill `NaN`, you need to convert 0 to `NaN`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the comment has partially answered this but I stumbled across this and thought I'd add a full answer to help future visitors.

In order for DataFrame.interpolate() to work, the 0 values in your data column must be replaced with NaN values. The following code should do the trick:

```
temp_df = upsampled.replace(0, np.nan)
inter_poly = temp_df.interpolation(method='spline', order=1)

>>> inter_poly

2016-01-31    17.0
2016-02-29    18.7
2016-03-31    20.3
2016-04-30    22.0
2016-05-31    23.7
2016-06-30    25.3
2016-07-31    27.0
2016-08-31    28.7
2016-09-30    30.3
2016-10-31    32.0
```

This gives you an interpolated data column, removing the NaNs.